# Accidentally replaced joomla with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I've accidentally installed wordpress into a production joomla directory. The website is not mine, how do I fixed it?

I'm assuming that only the root directory would be affected, so delete all wordpress directories and replace the index.php with the one from joomla, but it still gives a blank page. What do I do?

Comment: check the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using Akeeba Backup and making routine backups of your Joomla installations.

Then you can use kickstart.php (also Akeeba) and have a site backup up and working within 2 minutes.

It's the best bet - just in case of things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it appears that it was using a legacy version of joomla that's why the one I replaced failed.

I was able to fix this by replacing it again with another index.php from a lower version of joomla